# How to set a custom principal object during or after JWT authentication?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I've changed the way a user is authenticated in my backend. From now on I am receiving JWT tokens from Firebase which are then validated on my Spring Boot server.

This is working fine so far but there's one change which I am not too happy about and it's that the principal-object is now a `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt` and not a `AppUserEntity`, the user-model, like before.

```java
// Note: "authentication" is a JwtAuthenticationToken

Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Jwt jwt = (Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

So, after some reading and debugging I found that the `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` essentially sets the `Authentication` object like so:

```java
// BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java

AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = this.authenticationManagerResolver.resolve(request);

// Note: authenticationResult is our JwtAuthenticationToken
Authentication authenticationResult = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationRequest);  

SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
context.setAuthentication(authenticationResult);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
```

and as we can see, this on the other hand comes from the `authenticationManager` which is a `org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager` and so on. The rabbit hole goes deep.

I didn't find anything that would allow me to somehow replace the `Authentication`.

#### So what's the plan?

Since Firebase is now taking care of user authentication, a user can be created without my backend knowing about it yet. I don't know if this is the best way to do it but I intend to simply create a user record in my database once I discover a valid JWT-token of a user which does not exist yet.

Further, a lot of my business logic currently relies on the principal being a user-entity business object. I could change this code but it's tedious work and who doesn't want to look back on a few lines of legacy code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it a bit different than Julian Echkard.

In my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I am setting a `Customizer` like so:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt(new JwtResourceServerCustomizer(this.customAuthenticationProvider));
}
```

The `customAuthenticationProvider` is a `JwtResourceServerCustomizer` which I implemented like this:

```java
public class JwtResourceServerCustomizer implements Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.JwtConfigurer> {

    private final JwtAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    public JwtResourceServerCustomizer(JwtAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.customAuthenticationProvider = customAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.JwtConfigurer jwtConfigurer) {
        String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        AnonymousAuthenticationProvider anonymousAuthenticationProvider = new AnonymousAuthenticationProvider(key);
        ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(this.customAuthenticationProvider, anonymousAuthenticationProvider);
        jwtConfigurer.authenticationManager(providerManager);
    }
}
```

I'm configuring the `NimbusJwtDecoder` like so:

```
@Component
public class JwtConfig {

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        String jwkUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com";
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkUri)
                .build();
    }

}
```

And finally, we need a custom `AuthenticationProvider` which will return the `Authentication` object we desire:

```java
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Autowired
    public JwtAuthenticationProvider(JwtDecoder jwtDecoder) {
        this.jwtDecoder = jwtDecoder;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        BearerTokenAuthenticationToken token = (BearerTokenAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        Jwt jwt;
        try {
            jwt = this.jwtDecoder.decode(token.getToken());
        } catch (JwtValidationException ex) {
            return null;
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        if (jwt.hasClaim("roles")) {
            List<String> rolesClaim = jwt.getClaim("roles");
            List<RoleEntity.RoleType> collect = rolesClaim
                    .stream()
                    .map(RoleEntity.RoleType::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            for (RoleEntity.RoleType role : collect) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.toString()));
            }
        }

        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(BearerTokenAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

According Josh Cummings answer in [issue #7834](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7834) make configuration:

```
public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http...
       .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(
             jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(JwtUtil::createJwtUser)))
    ...
    return http.build();
}
```

and implement factory method, e.g:

```
public class JwtUtil {
   public static JwtUser createJwtUser(Jwt jwt) {
      int id = ((Long) jwt.getClaims().get("id")).intValue();
      String rawRoles = (String) jwt.getClaims().get("roles");
      Set<Role> roles = Arrays.stream(rawRoles.split(" "))
        .map(Role::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
      return new JwtUser(jwt, roles, id);
   }
}

public class JwtUser extends JwtAuthenticationToken {
    public JwtUser(Jwt jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, int id) {
        super(jwt, authorities);
        ....
    }
}
```

Take in note, that controller's methods should inject `JwtUser jwtUser` without any `@AuthenticationPrincipal`

Answer (score 0):

> This is working fine so far but there's one change which I am not too happy about and it's that the principal-object is now a org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt and not a AppUserEntity, the user-model, like before.

In my application I have circumvented this by rolling my own `JwtAuthenticationFilter` instead of using `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter`, which then sets my `User` Entity as the `principal` in the `Authentication` object. However, in my case this constructs a `User` barely from the JWT claims, which might be bad practice: SonarLint prompts to use a DTO instead to mitigate the risk of somebody injecting arbitrary data into his user record using a compromised JWT token. I don't know if that is a big deal - if you can't trust your JWTs, you have other problems, IMHO.

> I don't know if this is the best way to do it but I intend to simply create a user record in my database once I discover a valid JWT-token of a user which does not exist yet.

Keep in mind that JWTs should be verified by your application in a stateless manner, solely by verifying their signature. You shouldn't hit the database every time you verify them. Therefor it would be better if you create a user record using a method call like

```java
void foo(@AuthenticationPrincipal final Jwt jwt) {
  // only invoke next line if reading JWT claims is not enough
  final User user = userService.findOrCreateByJwt(jwt);

  // TODO method logic
}
```

once you need to persist changes to the database that involve this user.

Comment: Hi! My JWTs are coming from a Google service account, so far, gets verified by the `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` if I am getting this right. I've seen that this is also doing some caching s.t. it does not check it on every request. By now I have a separate call `getOrCreateUser()` which the client calls at the beginnin. There's just one last thing though: user-roles. I am using the `has_role()` functionallity on my endpoints. The JWT contains a custom `roles` claim but the `Authentication` object needs them too. I know _how_ I can do this but got no idea where I _should_ do this.

Comment: Btw, can you show how you are replacing the `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter`? I think I already tried this but wasn't able to do this properly. I think I ended up writing my own `AthenticationProvider` - not sure if there is a simpler way.

Comment: Answering to 2nd question first: Replacing (or bypassing) the BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter happens automagically - you make Spring pick up your `JwtAuthenticationFIlter` into the Filter Chain by declaring it like this:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletRequest response,
        final FilterChain chain
    ) {
        // JWT logic (get header, if present verify, set authentication) 
}
```

(sorry for formatting)

Comment: To 1st question: `has_role()` invokes `getRoles()` on the `authenticationPrincipal` (IIRC without looking at the code, you might need to look it up), so you should map Google's roles to e.g. `List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>` when mapping the JWT claims to your `authenticationPrincipal` Object, which happens in the `JwtAuthenticationFilter`, IMHO.

Comment: I hope that helps, sorry that I can't share my auth code openly on the web, I'm sure you understand

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
```

won't work for

```
request.getUserPrincipal();
```

you may create a custom class extending HttpServletRequestWrapper

```java
import java.security.Principal;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class UserPrincipalHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

  private final Principal principal;

  public UserPrincipalHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal) {
    super(request);
    this.principal = principal;
  }

  @Override
  public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
    return principal;
  }
}
```

then in your filter do something like this:

```java
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request){
    
    . . . 

    // create user details, roles are required
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SOME ROLE"));
    UserDetails userDetails = new User("SOME USERNAME", "SOME PASSWORD", authorities);

    // Create an authentication token
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

    // follow the filter chain, using the new wrapped UserPrincipalHtppServletRequest
    chain.doFilter(new UserPrincipalHttpServletRequest(request, usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken), response);
    // all filters coming up, will be able to run request.getUserPrincipal()
}
```